# Is every integer a mixed sum of three squares?

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

Lagrange's four-square theorem states that every natural number can be represented as the sum of four integer squares $n = a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2$.

*Question*: Is every integer a mixed sum of three integer squares $n = \pm a^2\pm b^2 \pm c^2$ ?

Note that the signs are independently positive or negative, for example $28 = 36-9+1$.

Comment: n=28 is a counter example

Comment: @JackFrost, $28=25+4-1=36+1-9=49-25+4=\ldots$.

Comment: But that alternates signs. The OP said $n=\pm{}a^2\pm{}b^2\pm{}c^2.$ So they all must have the same sign

Comment: @JackFrost, I don't think that's what the OP means.  I'm pretty sure he means the signs are independently positive or negative.

Comment: @BarryCipra: yes, is there a better notation for that?

Comment: Check here : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_three-square_theorem

Comment: @SébastienPalcoux, I don't know of a better notation, but sometimes it helps to give an example or two.

Comment: SébastienPalcoux: Your notation is fine: @JackFrost is simply being difficult. The notation for his interpretation would be $\pm(a^2+b^2+c^2)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write every number $n$ in the form $a^2+b^2-c^2$.  Just pick $a$ so that $n-a^2$ is odd and then solve

$$\begin{align}
b+c&=n-a^2\\
b-c&=1
\end{align}$$

for $b$ and $c$:

$$\begin{align}
b&={n-a^2+1\over2}\\
c&={n-a^2-1\over2}
\end{align}$$

Comment: There is a standard list of these universal indefinite ternary forms, in Dickson (1939). I see, in earlier pages he shows that any such form must nontrivially represent $0;$ he also allows square factors of some things.

Comment: @WillJagy, I was just giving a quick construction to answer the OP's question.

Comment: I know, I was  letting you know in case you might be interested.

Comment: @WillJagy, I appreciate it.  Changing notation slightly, I wonder if there might be three coefficients $a$, $b$, and $c$ such that no single fixed choice of signs gives a ternary form $\pm ax^2\pm by^2\pm cz^2$ that represents all integers $n$, but every $n$ is represented by at least one choice of signs.

Comment: Oh, sure, together $x^2 + y^2 - 3 z^2$ and $-x^2 - y^2 + 3 z^2$ ought to cover everything, but each has congruence obstructions: the first is never $9^k (9 n + 6)$ (including negative $n$)because, if divisible by $3,$ both $x$ and $y$ must be divisible by $3.$ The other form, its negative, misses $9^k (9 n + 3).$ I will need to check some things to confirm, but that should work.

Comment: yes, each class number $1$ so anything locally represented is globally represented. In both Dickson 1939 book and 1929, called Studies in the Theory of Numbers.

Comment: @WillJagy, very nice, but not quite what I'm looking for, since the sign choice $x^2-y^2+3z^2$ covers everything all by itself (by the argument in my answer).  I want none of the *eight* sign choices to suffice alone (and ideally, come to think of it, no subset of seven, either...).

Comment: Alright, that will take me some time. I will fiddle with it after the dentist, primarily just run some computer experiments, if something interesting appears see if I can prove it. I think no subset of seven is too much to expect.  Oh, I had forgotten, indefinite ternaries are anisotropic at an even number of finite primes; $x^2 + y^2 - 3 z^2$ is also never $4^k(8n+7),$ where we allow $n$ negative as well as positive.

Answer (score 4):

around 1930, L. E. Dickson and his students, A.  Oppenheim and A. E. Ross, found all indefinite ternary quadratic forms (up to $SL_3 \mathbb Z$ equivalence) with squarefree "discriminant" that do represent all integers. Three out of four infinite families are indicated on page 161 of Modern Elementary Theory of Numbers by Dickson. With odd and squarefree $N,$ also squarefree $M,$ both allowed positive or negative, the four are
$$ xy - M z^2, $$
$$ 2xy - N z^2, $$
$$ 2xy + y^2 - N z^2, $$
$$ 2xy + y^2 - 2N z^2. $$

In particular
$$ g(u,v,w) = 2 uv - w^2 $$
is evidently universal, if the target number $n$ is even take $w=0$ and $v=1$  and $u=n/2.$ If $n$ is odd take $w=1.$

Take your
$$ f(x,y,z) = x^2 - y^2 - z^2  $$
along with $g(u,v,w) = n.$ Then
$$ f(u+v+w, u + w, v+w) = (u+v+w)^2 - (u+w)^2 - (v+w)^2 = g(u,v,w) = n. $$
Note that I have indicated a linear change of variables with determinant $1,$ so that its inverse will also have integer coefficients. This is the $SL_3 \mathbb Z$ equivalence I indicated, and the reason for taking a roundabout path to a simple fact.